# Google Maps intent "google.navigation:q=lat,lng" wrong navigation, some wrong address instead of coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, maps

google.navigation:q=lat,lng intent is navigating to a wrong random ADDRESS instead of specified coordinates. It is autoselecting an address somehow. This is happening on android only. Coordinates are correct, checked manually and it works. Any directions ?

Coordinates used are: 40.23655411,-78.01329241

Google maps navigates to: 7576 Castle Mountain Ln instead.
Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? this is not a correct behaviour.

Code (react native):

```
Linking.openURL("google.navigation:q=40.23655411,-78.01329241&mode=d");
```

Comment: What have to done so far? Post your code

Comment: Share your intent code here.

Comment: Updated post with code. Please see above. @AndroidPlayer_Shree

Comment: @Bhoomi shared in the post